# Flutter - Upload file from gallery or camera to firestore => I get an error: _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, null

I'm trying to take picture from Gallery or Camera, and upload it to Firestore.
I have a problem when I get into the Gallery/Camera, and I don't take any picture. When I want to 'pop' back from Gallery\Camera without any image taken, I get an error:
**_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)**
in this row:

```
await ref.putFile(imageFile!);
```

I had the same problem when I tried just to take picture from Gallery/Camera without uploading it to Firestore, but I solved it with this code:

```
if (pickedFile == null) {
      imageFile ==
          Image.network(
              'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/08/08/09/17/avatar-1577909_1280.png');
    } else {
      setState(() {
        imageFile = File(pickedFile.path);
      });
```

The complete code from this screen is below:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_cropper/image_cropper.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:test_two/screens/screen_three.dart';

class ScreenFour extends StatefulWidget {
  ScreenFour({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ScreenFour> createState() => _ScreenFourState();
}

class _ScreenFourState extends State<ScreenFour> {

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  File? imageFile;
  String? imageUrl;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('SEND IMAGE TO FIRESTORE')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  _showImageOrGalleryDialog();
                },
                child: const Text(
                  '''TAP TO IMPORT PICTURE FROM CAMERA OR GALLERY AND SEND IT TO FIRESTORE''',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                )),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.white),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
              ),
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                child: imageFile == null
                    ? Image.network(
                        'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/08/08/09/17/avatar-1577909_1280.png',
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      )
                    : Image.file(
                        imageFile!,
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _getImagesFromGallery() async {
    final User? user = _auth.currentUser;
    final _uid = user?.uid;
    XFile? pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
      maxWidth: 1080,
      maxHeight: 1080,
    );

    // I had the same problem here, so I wrote the code below, and it worked
    if (pickedFile == null) {
      imageFile ==
          Image.network(
              'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/08/08/09/17/avatar-1577909_1280.png');
    } else {
      setState(() {
        imageFile = File(pickedFile.path);
      });
    }
    Navigator.pop(context);

    // Upload image to Firestore
    final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child('userImages')
        .child(_uid! + '.jpg');
    await ref.putFile(imageFile!);
    imageUrl = await ref.getDownloadURL();
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('profileImages')
        .doc(_uid)
        .set({'userImage': imageUrl});
  }

  void _getImagesFromCamera() async {
    final User? user = _auth.currentUser;
    final _uid = user?.uid;
    XFile? pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.camera,
      maxWidth: 1080,
      maxHeight: 1080,
    );
    if (pickedFile == null) {
      imageFile ==
          Image.network(
              'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/08/08/09/17/avatar-1577909_1280.png');
    } else {
      setState(() {
        imageFile = File(pickedFile.path);
      });
    }
    Navigator.pop(context);

    // Upload image to Firestore
    final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child('userImages')
        .child(_uid! + '.jpg');
    await ref.putFile(imageFile!);
    imageUrl = await ref.getDownloadURL();
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('profileImages')
        .doc(_uid)
        .set({'userImage': imageUrl});
  }

  void _showImageOrGalleryDialog() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('please choose an option'),
          content: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  _getImagesFromCamera();
                },
                child: Row(
                  children: const [
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Icon(Icons.camera),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Camera',
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  _getImagesFromGallery();
                },
                child: Row(
                  children: const [
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Icon(Icons.image),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Gallery',
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I'm really stuck with this code for few days.
Thank you guys in advance for your help!

Comment: Move the code to upload to firestore inside the else condition

Comment: @SankethB.K thank you man! That single line of yours is the solution to all my headache!